# NestJS: Option to make file in endpoint optional

Tags: express, nestjs

I am using NestJS to create REST API and I am trying to create an endpoint that will require certain body but also accept file that should be optional.

```
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
@Post('create')
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file', { }))
async createPost(@Req() req: any, @Body() createPostDto: CreatePostDto, @UploadedFile(new ParseFilePipeBuilder().addMaxSizeValidator({ maxSize: 2048 }).build({ errorHttpStatusCode: HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY })) file: Express.Multer.File) {
        return await this.postsService.createPost(req.user, createPostDto, file);
}
```

But using this code makes the file required at all times as seen in this error response:

```json
{
    "statusCode": 422,
    "message": "File is required",
    "error": "Unprocessable Entity"
}
```

Is there a way to make the upload file optional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an answer on NestJS discord. I changed ParseFilePipeBuilder to ParseFilePipe which supports `fileIsRequired` option.

```
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
@Post('create')
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file', { }))
async createPost(@Req() req: any, @Body() createPostDto: CreatePostDto, @UploadedFile(new ParseFilePipe({
        validators: [
            new MaxFileSizeValidator({ maxSize: parseInt(process.env.MAX_FILE_UPLOAD_SIZE) * 1000 })
        ],
        fileIsRequired: false
    })) file?: Express.Multer.File) {
        return await this.postsService.createPost(req.user, createPostDto, file);
    }
```

Comment: Should mention that this behavior is also possible even with ParseFilePipeBuilder  - you can add 'fileIsRequired: false' to the build options.

Answer (score 4):

Just found a perfect working solution for this this after searching the whole web.
just add `fileIsRequired: false` to your code inside the build options:

```
 .build({
  fileIsRequired: false,
  errorHttpStatusCode: HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
 }),
```

So your updated code will be:

```
enter code here
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
@Post('create')
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file', {}))
async createPost(
@Req() req: any,
@Body() createPostDto: CreatePostDto,
@UploadedFile(
  new ParseFilePipeBuilder()
    .addMaxSizeValidator({ maxSize: 2048 })
    .build({
      fileIsRequired: false,
      errorHttpStatusCode: HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
    }),
)
file: Express.Multer.File,
) {
 return await this.postsService.createPost(req.user, createPostDto, file);
}
```